# Getting array from PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My db table looks like that

[image]

I'm trying to get page title and content from this function

```
function page($current, $lang){
    global $db;
    $txt='txt_'.$lang;
    $title='title_'.$lang;
    $data=$db->query("SELECT '$txt', '$title' FROM pages WHERE `id`='$current'");
    $data=$data->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    return $data;
}
```

Then at the beginning of the index page getting array values

`$data=page($id, $lang);`

And using like this example

```
<title><?=$data[1]?></title>
```

But getting every time the same result `title_en` (en is my language variable.). What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't single quote your fields. MySQL interprets this as a string.

```
$data=$db->query("SELECT $txt, $title FROM pages WHERE `id` = $current");
```

Alternatively you can use backticks in MySQL. But note that `$current` still shouldn't have them assuming it's an integer field.

```
$data=$db->query("SELECT `$txt`, `$title` FROM pages WHERE `id` = $current");
```

Comment: To clarify, when you single quote your fields, you are essentially asking the database for constant strings. It's like saying "give me a copy of the string $title for every row in the database"

Comment: @Robert Martin, nice additional clarification, I have added it to my answer.

Comment: `$data=$db->query("SELECT  n.name, p.$txt, p.$title FROM pages AS p, nav AS n WHERE `id`=$current");` WHAT'S WRONG IN THIS CODE?

Comment: One thing at a time friend. You should post another question if you are progressing further down the rabbit hole (as it seems from your new query).